# includeInDownload not work - Supplemental Document

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I have an envelope with some documents, and one of them I do not want to be concatenated when you download the documents using the `combined` option. By reading the documentation, I found the `includeInDownload` attribute that can be passed to the documents when creating an envelope. But when I am creating the envelope, it seems that this attribute is being ignored, because after creating the envelope, I search the documents and the `includeInDownload` attribute is `true`. The envelope creation JSON:

```
{
  "status": "created",
  "emailSubject": "Example envelope",
  "emailBlurb": "Example",
  "documents": [{
    "documentId": "1",
    "name": "Test 1",
    "remoteUrl": "URL"
  },
  {
    "documentId": "2",
    "name": "Test 2",
    "remoteUrl": "URL",
    "includeInDownload": "false"
  }],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [{
      "name": "Lisa Simpson",
      "email": "lisa@email.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "clientUserId": "1"
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the 'display' attribute as well for what we call "supplemental" documents.
If  display=modal, the associated document is a supplement.
If display=inline, it’s not a supplement.